# Why local variable in C# must be initialized after initializing and cast inside If operator condition?

Tags: c#, if-statement, initialization, pattern-matching, local-variables

```
public void A()
{
    if (!(_s is string v))
        return;

    Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

This code compiles good
But

```
public void A()
{
    if (false == _s is string v)
        return;

    Console.WriteLine(v); <-- 'Local variable 'v' might not be initialized before accessing'
}
```

But this returns compiler error
What's the reason?

Comment: I guess it is due to opertors precedence, i.e. type check and equality check might go before `v` assignement, thus, if equality fails, there will be no assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow analysis isn't perfect.

```
if (true == _s is string v)
  Console.WriteLine(v);
```

also fails.

Definite assignment flow analysis is conservative - its purpose is to make sure you can't read an unassigned local. It's desirable for it to also be able to figure out branches that can never be reached given a set of conditions, but that's a bonus.

In the end, you would need to do a specific analysis to handle the case of `false == _s is string v`. But why, when there's no reason not to use `!(_s is string)`, which is handled just fine? You can always do the analyzer more complicated, but there's also a value to keeping it simple.

Comment: I understand that, but why is it implemented like this?

Comment: @Murrelken As I said, you can always make the analyzer more complicated. But that takes effort, code that needs to be debugged, creates opportunities for subtle bugs... Why bother, when there's really no legitimate use for such a condition, at best a few silly C programmers unable to get rid of their C habits? :) It's not as if there was a perfect analyzer that somebody explicitly changed to not handle the specific case you're talking about - the feature was never there, and someone would need to add it. In fact, you _can't_ make a perfect flow analyzer; you *have* to make trade-offs.

Comment: I accept those compromises you are talking about. But I'm not looking for just thoughts **why** is it work like this. I want to know **how** is it work actually

Comment: @Murrelken The whole C# compiler is open sourced. Give yourself a stroll - https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/FlowAnalysis :) In the actual implementation, the true and false cases for reachability/data flow analysis depend on either constant values or known expressions (such as the IsPattern you care about); it doesn't seem to handle expressions like `x == y`, while it does evaluate e.g. `true`, `(o is string s)` or `x && y`. It isn't exactly easy reading, though. A lot of it is documented, but not this particular case in the analysis.